# Running su with -c gives unrecognized command error

Tags: linux, su

I am trying to run a command as another user in Linux. Here is what I run:

```
su user1 -c '/bin/mkdir /tmp/zz'
```

However, this gives me this error:

```
fatal: unrecognized command '/bin/mkdir /tmp/zz'
```

Comment: su user1 -c '/bin/mkdir /tmp/zz' works for me (using Ubuntu Precise). What is the shell of user1?

Answer (score 1):

You need to swap the single quotes for double quotes. Not that these are only required with commands that take parameters, or if you chain several commands together.

```
su user1 -c "/bin/mkdir /tmp/zz"
```

Comment: Now that's cute.  The guy who downvoted me culled his own response, but didn't change his mind on my answer. :(

Comment: I agree, don't use single quotes for `su` as they often makes trouble

Answer (score 0):

As suggested by Mark Wagner, I encountered the same problem when the user had a non-standard shell (in my case it was git-shell). And the solution was to do:

```
su -s /bin/bash -c 'some command'
```